# Building Jekyll with docker and serving with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, jekyll

I made a simple jekyll project and a Dockerfile like below:

```
FROM jekyll/builder AS dev_builder

WORKDIR /srv/jekyll

COPY Gemfile Gemfile*.lock ./

RUN bundle install

COPY . .

ENV JEKYLL_ENV=production
RUN jekyll build

FROM nginx:alpine AS prod_serv

COPY --from=dev_builder /srv/jekyll/_site /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When I try to build image with `docker build -t nginx_jekyll:0.1 .` I get this error:

`COPY failed: stat .. merged/srv/jekyll/_site: no such file or directory`

I searched but couldn't find a solution for it.

I can successfully build with this command `docker run --rm -it --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" --volume="$PWD/vendor/bundle:/usr/local/bundle" --env JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll/builder jekyll build`

How can I properly build jekyll and serve it via nginx with docker?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why am I cannot complete building process but I tried to copy folders via code below, I have builded image successfully with it.

```
FROM jekyll/builder AS builder

WORKDIR /srv/jekyll

COPY Gemfile Gemfile*.lock ./

RUN bundle install

COPY . .

ENV JEKYLL_ENV=production
RUN jekyll build && cp -r ./_site /build

FROM nginx:alpine AS serv

COPY --from=builder /build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This is not working (cp: can't stat './_site': No such file or directory):

```
RUN jekyll build
RUN cp -r ./_site /build
```

but this is:

```
RUN jekyll build && cp -r ./_site /build
```

Comment: Why do you even do that? You are making the first build layer bigger for no reason.